# Pass Intel XDK javascript function result to php

Tags: javascript, php, intel-xdk

Good day,
I am creating a scanning function with Intel XDK with code as below:

```
$(document).on("click", "#scan", function(evt)
{
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

         function onDeviceReady() 
         {
               intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
         }

   //this event is fired when scanning is completed
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan",function(evt){
        if (evt.success == true) {
            //successful scan
            var quantity = evt.codedata;
            alert(evt.codedata);

            }
        else 
        {
            //failed scan
            alert("Please try again");
        }
    },false);
    });
```

On button press on device the scan is initiated and performs perfectly.
What I now need to do is to pass the result to a PHP server side script.
Please help me with an example of how to do this.
regards